# TypeScript: Index signature is missing in type

Tags: casting, typescript

I want `MyInterface.dic` to be like a dictionary `name: value`, and I define it as follows:

```
interface MyInterface {
    dic: { [name: string]: number }
}
```

Now I create a function which waits for my type:

```
function foo(a: MyInterface) {
    ...
}
```

And the input:

```
let o = {
    dic: {
        'a': 3,
        'b': 5
    }
}
```

I'm expecting `foo(o)` to be correct, but the compiler is falling:

```
foo(o) // TypeScript error: Index signature is missing in type { 'a': number, 'b': number }
```

I know there is a possible casting: `let o: MyInterface = { ... }` which do the trick, but **why** is TypeScript not recognizing my type?

---

Extra: works fine if `o` is declared inline:

```
foo({
  dic: {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 5
  }
})
```

Comment: I am looking for answers to this one: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24469

Comment: It seems as of now this exact code passes in Typescript without any issues: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAWYB7EcoCeyA3gFDIXIAmGAXCeZUwNp4C2E9AzmFKAOYBdeiACubAEbQANIwoBfUotIxRITDhDIY2bAAps9dBtz4CAShLKANhDDJsyALwMmNBPTJMmAcjg-6AEZZb0ofCQDkACYQykVlHX1scwBuIA

Comment: The same issue can still occur in other scenarios like the one described in [this TS issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300). As suggested by several people in this thread, the solution is to use `type` rather than `interface` in that case, because interfaces require _by design_ explicit index signatures in those cases.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The problem is that when the type is inferred, then the type of `o` is:

```
{ dic: { a: number, b: number } }
```

That's not the same as `{ dic: { [name: string]: number } }`. Critically, with the top signature you're not allowed to do something like `o.dic['x'] = 1`. With the 2nd signature you are.

They are equivalent types at runtime (indeed, they're the exact same value), but a big part of TypeScript's safety comes from the fact that these aren't the same, and that it'll only let you treat an object as a dictionary if it knows it's explicitly intended as one. This is what stops you accidentally reading and writing totally non-existent properties on objects.

The solution is to ensure TypeScript knows that it's intended as a dictionary. That means:

- Explicitly providing a type somewhere that tells it it's a dictionary:

  `let o: MyInterface`
- Asserting it to be a dictionary inline:

  `let o = { dic: <{ [name: string]: number }> { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } }`
- Ensuring it's the initial type that TypeScript infers for you:

  `foo({ dic: { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } })`

If there's a case where TypeScript thinks it's a normal object with just two properties, and then you try to use it later as a dictionary, it'll be unhappy.

Comment: > With the 2nd signature you are. 

Actually My IDE's doesnot allow me to do `o.dic.x`

Comment: Good catch, sorry, that should've been index syntax (`o.dic['x'] = 1`). Example updated.

Comment: Update! TypeScript 2 should now automatically do this conversion for you, if it's valid: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#implicit-index-signatures

Comment: This is so stupid, can't believe Microsoft botched this, if X is a subset of Y it should be easy to cast X as Y without hassle. Right now TS can't cast `[key: string]: string | number` but it can cast `[key: string]: any` despite an interface only having strings and numbers

Comment: Spread operator helps in my case - I don't need to modify the object, so `bar({ ...hash })` works for me.

Comment: As of today, it seems to work, so long as you use types, rather than interfaces. See @Nikolay's answer.

Comment: Is the reason that typescript objects to the `foo(o)` call when `foo` declares `o` as `{ dic: { [name: string]: number } }` is that the interface allows `foo` to add additional properties to `o`, which would break its inferred type of `{ dic: { a: number, b: number } }`?

Comment: Type works but Interface does not. See https://codesandbox.io/s/type-vs-interface-kw1j0v?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 47):

TS wants us to define the type of the index. For example, to tell the compiler that you can index the object with **any string**, e.g. `myObj['anyString']`, change:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myVal: string;
}
```

to:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [key: string]: string;
  myVal: string;
}
```

And you can now store any string value on any string index:

```
x['myVal'] = 'hello world'
x['any other string'] = 'any other string'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkBtAawnQC5kBnMKUAcwF07HmQWBuE5AFt0ANTgAbTk1b8AvkSIIA9iEbJIjOhmyRYiFAF5CA4WMnIARBrAWANEXmKVa6wCYtWHHvxHipUxJ0VhCMrnYCcABGCEEAjK4AzOGyQA).

Comment: This is the way to go if you don't want to loose `myVal` typing + autocomplete feature

Comment: but you lose type safety when you do that. `myInterface` was only meant to have `myVal` property, now it can have any property.

Comment: Yes, this question was asked by a person who wanted to be able to store some value on an arbitrary index. I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 43):

For me, the error was solved by using *type* instead of *interface*.

This error can occur when function `foo` has *type* instead of *interface* for the typing parameter, like:

```
type MyType {
   dic: { [name: string]: number }
}

function foo(a: MyType) {}
```

But the passed value typed with interface like

```
interface MyInterface {
    dic: { [name: string]: number }
}

const o: MyInterface = {
    dic: {
        'a': 3,
        'b': 5
    }
}

foo(o) // type error here
```

I just used

```
const o: MyType = {
    dic: {
        'a': 3,
        'b': 5
    }
}

foo(o) // It works
```

Comment: Can you explain what type error you get and why using type over interface should help?  I cannot reproduce what you claim: this [Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuAmAlgMYBc6UA2gHYCGAthGQM7ABOBVA5gLplUCudAEYRWUAL7ZxUbNgBm-KkWAEA9lShzVqgBQ0ycRJACU6SVmwdgouTSLQ4ASSrXWt++my58xMmkq0DMxsHDx8giJi5ubYROosUKoGIM6u7iieON6EpJne+VAA5DSFZADMADReBbiFQqVQAKzVuNGyWFq6qqYA9D1QoJBQoqyqYgAWohDYQA) works as expected. Maybe your answer is outdated (I'm using typescript 4.3.5)

Answer (score 41):

In my case, it was just necessary to use `type` instead of `interface`.

Comment: Same for me, but why is this?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300. By design interfaces and types behave differently when it comes to index signatures.

Answer (score 31):

You can solve this problem by doing `foo({...o})`
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBtEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwF0GQBXagI2hEAvkVCRYiFBgAiwBGEIkyMAParufQVBFEYPEAuCqQyNaoAUcBhmwS8EAJRKyyBCcaqANhAB0X1TYrR10iIncQZmQANzgvG3Q5BWQAXkIzdQYARmRRIgB6fORoKFUoRgKi8wtYrxCwwuQwAAtgRmQAdzKAawrqgmRfIdrcxyA)

Comment: This is not much more than a link-only answer. Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67219058/edit)? (But ******* ***without*** ******* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 21):

Here are my two cents:

```js
type Copy<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

genericFunc<SomeType>() // No index signature

genericFunc<Copy<SomeType>>() // No error
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is a bit wider than OP's question.

For example, let's define an interface and variable of the interface

```js
interface IObj {
  prop: string;
}

const obj: IObj = { prop: 'string' };
```

Can we assign `obj` to type `Record<string, string>`?

The answer is **No**. [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArZBvAKGWTGDABsIAuZAZzClAHMBuAgXwIIQHsR7kPHDQw5kAXnxESZSjQDkpChHkAaDm258BUCLygATGgCU9PQwB56jEE1V0GzAHwTBONkA)

```js
// TS2322: Type 'IObj' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IObj'.
const record: Record<string, string> = obj;
```

Why this is happening?
To describe it let's refresh our understanding of "**upcasting**" and "**downcasting**" terms, and what is the meaning of "L" letter in SOLID principles.

The following examples work without errors because we assign the "wider" type to the more strict type.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2B5ARgKxgXhgG8AoGGZKNAUwC4YBySmhgGjJgDd0BXOmACwAmdgF8A3CRIIo1AE4AzFMGowAktjylyzftDkIA5pNFTQkWCFz0NuAvETJ0m8TAD0bmADkQMeXJA5GAALeWopKxwAOl1JSKjuND5XDxgABQCAB3koAE9GRL4GGAATEGoIGDAQWGoADzhoGHAKXOzGWxwGKIAKIQBmfoBOAEoSIA)

```js
const initialObj = {
  title: 'title',
  value: 42,
};

interface IObj {
  title: string;
}

const obj: IObj = initialObj; // No error here

obj.title;
obj.value; // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IObj'.(2339)
```

`IObj` requires only one prop so the assignment is correct.

The same works for Type. [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2B5ARgKxgXhgG8AoGGZKNAUwC4YBySmhgGjJgDd0BXOmACwAmdgF8A3CRJQAngAdqMACrY8hUuWb9oAJwQBzSaKmhIsELnorcBeImTpVkkhZwA6LZNdvuaPuJgAekCYAAUdEAUdWUZfPgYYABMQaggYMBBYagAPOGgYcAp5RQZrHAY3AAohAGYagE4AShIgA)

```js
const initialObj = {
  title: 'title',
  value: 42,
};

type TObj = {
  title: string;
}

const obj: TObj = initialObj; // No error here

obj.title;
obj.value; // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'TObj'.(2339)
```

The last two examples work without errors because of "upcasting". It means that we cast a value type to the "upper" type, to the entity type which can be an ancestor. In other words, we can assign Dog to Animal but can not assign Animal to Dog ([See meaning of "L" letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in SOLID principles). Assigning the Dog to the Animal is "upcasting" and this is safe operation.

`Record<string, string>` is much wider than the object with just one property. It can have any other properties.

```js
const fn = (record: Record<string, string>) => {
  record.value1;
  record.value2;
  record.value3; // No errors here
}
```

That's why when you assign the `IObj` Interface to `Record<string, string>` you get an Error. You assign it to the type that extends `IObj`. `Record<string, string>` type can be a descendant of `IObj`.

In other answers, it is mentioned that using of **Type** can fix the problem. But I believe it is wrong behavior and we should avoid of using it.

[Example:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg8gIwFZQLxQN4CgpWAS2ABsIAuKAZ2ACd8A7AcwG4sBfLLAYwHs6qpuycvGRpMOPIRLkA5AWIQZAGjYsOPPsCgAzOmIAU1CD2oATcgCVj3MwB4qtRkso16DAHwBKNO-G4jJqYAdABuAIZEAK4QAIws-tZmoRHRAEzxUAE2weFREADMTFAA9MVQAHLcUBDU1DYUUAAWNRBsHLr6gkieRaUVVTV11E0tWEA)

```js
type TObj = {
  title: string;
}

const obj: TObj = {
  title: 'title',
};


const fn = (record: Record<string, string>) => {
  record.value1;
  record.value2;
  // No errors here because according to types any string property is correct
  // UPD:
  // FYI: TS has a flag `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` which changes this behavior so every prop becomes optional
  record.value3; 
}

fn(obj); // No error here but it has to be here because of downcasting
```

[The last example with the comparison of Type and Interface.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#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-mW1ZtCJkCFs6ZrJYrSXrTYoHgwZDJHjU1GQ0gFBrIC33ZDSuBnBAbLbIODIMWYSjSpMVlOCHCuDM8VkgZQQ4X+DUdYSKQRQfsDCCuYdi66kVkNAhAA)

P.S.

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) with related question, and interesting [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-371353444).

Answer (score 5):

This error is valid. You should write something like the options below:

```
const o = Object.freeze({dic: {'a': 3, 'b': 5}})
const o = {dic: {'a': 3, 'b': 5}} as const
const o: MyInterface = {dic: {'a': 3, 'b': 5}}
```

**Why?**

The TypeScript compiler cannot assume that `o` won't change between the time it is initialized and the time `foo(o)` is called.

Maybe somewhere in your code something like the snippet below is written:

```
delete o.dic
```

That's why the inline version works. In this case there isn't any possible update.

Answer (score 3):

The following simple trick might be useful too:

```
type ConvertInterfaceToDict<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
```

This conversion helped me to fix the issue:

> Argument of type 'QueryParameters' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Record<string, string>

Where QueryParameters is an Interface. I wasn't able to modify it directly because it comes from a third party package.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the top result for the search term. If you already have an index type with (string, string) and you can't change type of that input, then you can also do this:

```
foo({...o}) // Magic
```

For your question, another way to do it is:

```
interface MyInterface {
    [name: string]: number
}

function foo(a: MyInterface) {
    ...
}

let o = {
   'a': 3,
   'b': 5
}

foo(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

If switching from `interface` to `type` was not helped, here enforced solution with `type`, which is working for me:

```js
type MyInterface {
    dic: { [name: string]: number } | {};
}

function foo(a: MyInterface) {
    ...
}

let o = {
    dic: {
        'a': 3,
        'b': 5
    }
}

foo(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution: use Type instead of Interface

#### Use case:

```
interface GenericMap {
  [key: string]: SomeType;
}

export class MyClass<SpecificMap extends GenericMap = GenericMap> {

  private readonly map = {} as SpecificMap;

  constructor(keys: (keyof SpecificMap)[]) {
    for (const key of keys) {
      this.statusMap[key] = //... whatever as SomeType ;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Does not work:

```
interface MyMap {
  myKey1: SomeType;
  myKey2: SomeType;
}

const myObject = new MyClass<MyMap>('myKey1', 'myKey2');

// TS2344: Type MyMap does not satisfy the constraint GenericMap
Index signature for type string is missing in type MyMap
```

#### Works but it is not type-safe anymore:

```
interface MyMap {
  [key: string]: SomeType;
  myKey1: SomeType;
  myKey2: SomeType;
}

const myObject = new MyClass<MyMap>('myKey1', 'myKey2', 'someRandomKey');

// 'someRandomKey' is now allowed but should not
```

#### Solution:

```
type MyMap = {
  myKey1: SomeType;
  myKey2: SomeType;
}

const myObject = new MyClass<MyMap>('myKey1', 'myKey2');

// works and does not allow random keys
```

Read more about index signatures: https://blog.herodevs.com/typescripts-unsung-hero-index-signatures-ddc3d1e34c9f