# Passing an interface as a type with index signature in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to pass interface into a certain function in typescript, where that function can accept any object type, so long as all of its properties are of a certain type.

Consider the following [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20DoSomething(args%3A%20%7B%20readonly%20%5BpropertyName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyArgs%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20someArgs%3A%20MyArgs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ADoSomething(%7B%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20bar%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0ADoSomething(someArgs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20compile%20error%3A%20Index%20signature%20is%20missing%20in%20type%20'MyArgs'):

```
function DoSomething(args: { readonly [propertyName: string]: string }) {
    // do something
}

// MyArgs is really just a more strongly typed version of {[propertyName: string]: string}
interface MyArgs {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

var someArgs: MyArgs = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
}

DoSomething({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" }); // works
DoSomething(someArgs); // compile error: Index signature is missing in type 'MyArgs'
```

This doesn't work because `someArgs` can not be cast to the parameter type used for the function's argument.

This is different from [Typescript: Index signature is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006008) because of the readonly modifier which means that the `DoSomething` function cannot add new propertly to `args`. This means that an instance of `MyArgs` will still comply with this interface signature after `DoSomething` has been invoked against it.

How can I represent this in Typescript? Is there another way of doing this that I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Index signature is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006008/typescript-index-signature-is-missing-in-type)

Comment: It is related but I think it is different. Note the `readonly` modifier which means that the `DoSomething` function cannot add new propertly to `args`, which means that an instance of `MyArgs` will still comply with this signature after `DoSomething` has been invoked against it.

Comment: After removing `readonly` does typescript compile it? I don't think readonly or not does not make any difference here at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object literal type is assignable to a type with an index signature if the property types are compatible, but an interface type is not; see [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024).  Once you annotate `someArgs` as type `MyArgs`, the information that it was an object literal is lost and only the `MyArgs` type is used for checking assignability to the parameter type of `DoSomething`.  The `readonly` modifier is irrelevant: the question is whether `someArgs` satisfies TypeScript's (very imperfect) heuristic for being unlikely to have had non-string properties added *before* it is passed to `DoSomething`.

To make the example work, you can just change `MyArgs` to an object literal type:

```
type MyArgs = {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
};
```

Comment: Ah of course. The bit of insight I was lacking was that interfaces can be augmented. Thanks :)