# How do you officially create a type of a subset of a superset in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function which is supposed to broadcast the contents of a given type to whoever cares to receive it.

something like

```
function broadcast(J:Record<string,unknown>){...}
```

but when I got to apply a specific type to that function I get an error e.g.

```
interface foo
{
   thing: string;
}

const a:foo={thing:'wow'};

broadcast(a); // error that I am not using a specific type but broadcast doesn't care.
```

I have figured out I can unwrap the type like so:

```
broadcast((a as unknown) as Record<string,unknown>)
```

but I think there is a better way.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006008/typescript-index-signature-is-missing-in-type) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The below should work, instead of `unknown`, pass Record an argument of type `T`. Also you don't even need an `interface foo`.

```
function broadcast<T>(J : Record<string,T>){
    console.log(J)
}

const a = {thing:'wow'};

broadcast<string>(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you don't actually need a `foo` interface as it generates no value helping you keep your code type-safe.

The core issue with your code is the use of type `unknown`, anything can assign to unknown but unknown can't assign to anything but itself.

This is why your `foo` interface typed variable `a` can't be assigned to a parameter expecting `Record<string, unknown>`.

Replace it with `Record<string, any>` will make typescript happy again.

However, as I said earlier this extra interface guard `foo` generates no value so you might just consider remove it.

Comment: Thanks! The points was that broadcast wants a record type, foo is a kind of record type, but I don't want the TS linter complaining or the need to remove type checking completely (e.g. integers don't belong in broadcast). The use of a generic type was what I was thinking should work but I couldn't figure out the syntax to make it work. I think Mahesh answered the question.