# Why can't an interface be assigned to Record<string, unknown>?

Tags: typescript, object, types, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I just noticed that an interface cannot be assigned to `Record<string, unknown>` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyIArgLYBG0uAvrrguiAM5hGlqbIC8ObujIBGZE1YcuNOFDIAlCKygATADycooAOYAaZBRABrEOgDuIAHwDhQA)):

```js
interface Foo {
    foo: number
}

const foo: Foo = { foo: 1 }
const bar: Record<string, unknown> = foo
//    |-> Error: Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'
//               Index signature is missing in type 'Foo'.(2322)
```

However the same is possible, when the type declaration for `Foo` is omitted ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDe9EC4YEYYC+AUKJLAEYCGATjgEoCmo1AJgDzTUCWYA5gDQwArmADWYEAHcwAPhSYQQA)):

```js
const foo = { foo: 1 }
const bar: Record<string, unknown> = foo // no error here
```

**Question:** Why is there a difference between both examples? For me the reduced type of the variable `foo` is the same in both examples... Shouldn't the interface `Foo` be assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`?

In my understanding `Record<string, unknown>` is equivalent to `object` and thus any interface should be assignable to it. Also [@typescript-eslint/ban-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) suggests using `Record<string, unknown>` instead of `object`.

**Remarks:** The first example works when either `object` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyIArgLYBG0uAvrrguiAM5hGlqbIC8ObujIBGZE1YcuNOFDLoaAKwgIug4uiA)) or `Record<string, any>` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyIArgLYBG0uAvrrguiAM5hGlqbIC8ObujIBGZE1YcuNOFDIAlCKygATADycooAOYAaZHBABPAHwDhQA)) is used instead of `Record<string, unknown>`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You've run across [Index signature is missing in type (only on interfaces, not on type alias) #15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)

The code will work when you change an interface to a type:

```
type Foo = {
    foo: number
}

const foo: Foo = { foo: 1 };
const bar: Record<string, unknown> = foo;
```

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly counterintuitive.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: @Lesiak has the correct answer above. I'm leaving this solely for the link to the related answer.

Admittedly, I'm a bit out of my depth here, but I'm looking through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37006179/14956277) and I see:

> [A] big part of TypeScript's safety comes from the fact that [...] it'll only let you treat an object as a dictionary if it knows it's explicitly intended as one.

Which is consistent with my testing. Modifying your interface to explicitly treat `Foo.foo` as an index does not produce the error. ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIDaMmAXMgM5hSgDmAuhSAK4C2ARtLgL664J0IaslLoKGLAF4co8sgCMyPoOFhkHOFAoAlCIKgATADzVaIOgBpkLEAGsQ6AO4gAfMhligA))

```
interface Foo {
    [foo: string]: number
}

const foo = { foo: 1 }
const bar: Record<string, unknown> = foo
```

This doesn't answer your question fully, as `Record<string, any>` works with your explicit interface, but maybe someone more knowledgeable can take it from here.

Comment: Actually `interface Foo { foo: number, [key: string]: unknown }` should be the right solution [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyIArgLYBG0+hA2gNYQCeZAzmFKAOYBdMhRDMQ6AO4hcAX1y4E6ENyKk0mZAF4cq9GQCMyOYuVhkNOFDIAlCIqgATADzdeIPgBpkIsZJAA+LV0gA) since it means: "an object with a property `foo` of type `number` and it can be used as a dictionary"

Comment: In the linked thread there is a question why `Record<string, any>` from just 5 days ago: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-760165845 :-) I also wonder why this works...