# Why object doesn't conform type described by index signatures?

Tags: typescript

I have types [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AQQDYEsDW0C8UA3lANp4gBcUAzsAE5YB2A5gLrUCGTIUAvgG4AUKEhQAMljoQmEelEIAKACadgnavCSpMuCAEoFAPigA3APZZlw0dADKAVzBhz9YBGWS6C4mSvU6RlYOCSl3WXlBISFkDE4aGigAcQxzODtgV04WCAAeO3EoCAAPcOVEx2dXd08woyEiaL5o2ygAWRBKlzcPL2AfBqEoYagAImAAC2YWGlHqFTUNYltqUbB6FCxzB1moAB8xhAcmHFGAGihkc1T6VY24Uf2xuAwHCEeD0YB3KfdRvkM+BMFiswmaMXMTG8dCyOR8si+yVS6Uy9GyeQ6XWqvTqin0wmiQA) that descries some generic class:

```js
type ObjectAlike = { [key: string]: any }; // object with string indexed field with any type
type Listener = (data: ObjectAlike) => void; // function witch take one argument with ObjectAlike
type SupportedList = { [id: string]: Listener }; // list of Listener

class GlobStorage<SL extends SupportedList>
{

}
```

Then I use it like:

```js
type MySupportedList = 
{
    "things": (data: {type: "precious" | "junk", color: "reb" | "blue" | "white"}) => void;
}

const storage = new GlobStorage<MySupportedList>(); // Type 'MySupportedList' does not satisfy the constraint 'SupportedList'.
```

Why `MySupportedList` doesn't conform `SupportedList`, why  `Type 'ObjectAlike' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: "precious" | "junk"; color: "reb" | "blue" | "white"; }': type, color`? `ObjectAlike` describe object with `string` fields, which can have any type.

Comment: So in `MySupportedList` type is inffered as `{type: "precious" | "junk", color: "reb" | "blue" | "white"}` which is different from `{ [key: string]: any }`.

Comment: This comment gives more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006008/typescript-index-signature-is-missing-in-type?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment96038128_37006179